# In a shell script, when invoking beeline -e sql to execute an SQL statement

Tags: shell, hive, beeline

When executing beeline -e "alter table test.order_tb add partition(month='202305', day='20230524')" in the shell script, will the hive client resources be released immediately after the statement is executed?

I executed a shell script similar to the following on our cluster:

```bash
start_date=20230523
month_plex=${start_date:0:6}
end_date=20030103
while [ $start_date -ge $end_date ]; do
        beeline -e "alter table test.order_tb add partition(month='$month_plex', day='$start_date')"
        start_date=$(date -d "-1 day $start_date" + %y%m%d)
        month_plex=${start_date:0:6}
done
```

As a result, the people in the big data cluster reported that it caused delays to them, and the resources of the big data cluster were very tight. It can be seen that resources are not released immediately after executing beeline -e